# SQL Server : Group by with custom values to row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a SQL query

```
DELCARE @V_DATE DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) = @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) 
          THEN 'TODAY'
       WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) > @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) 
          THEN 'PENDING'
       WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) < @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) 
          THEN 'UPCOMING'
       WHEN UT.Status = 2 
          THEN 'COMPLETED'
       WHEN UT.Status = 3 
          THEN 'SKIPPED' 
    END,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS COUNT
FROM 
    USERTABLE UT
GROUP BY 
    UT.ScheduledDate, UT.Status
```

Suppose I have data like this where Status = 1-Pending, 2-Complete, 3-Skipped

```
ScheduledDate  | Status
---------------+-------
7/31/2018      | 1
8/01/2018      | 1
7/28/2018      | 1
7/28/2018      | 2
7/26/2018      | 3
```

How to get data like this

```
Name        | Count
------------+----------
TODAY       |  1
PENDING     |  1
UPCOMING    |  1
COMPLETED   |  1
SKIPPED     |  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`, or define a column with the name. You can do the latter using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT name, COUNT_BIG(*) AS COUNT
FROM USERTABLE UT OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) = @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) THEN 'TODAY'
                   WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) > @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) THEN 'PENDING'
                   WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) < @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) THEN 'UPCOMING'
                   WHEN UT.Status = 2 THEN 'COMPLETED'
                   WHEN UT.Status = 3 THEN 'SKIPPED' 
              END)
      ) v(name)
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` or `cte` to avoid `case` expression repetitions :

```
WITH t AS (
     SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) = @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) THEN 'TODAY'
                 WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) > @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) THEN 'PENDING'
                 WHEN CAST(UT.ScheduledDate AS DATE) < @V_DATE AND UT.Status = 1) THEN 'UPCOMING'
                 WHEN UT.Status = 2 THEN 'COMPLETED'
                 WHEN UT.Status = 3 THEN 'SKIPPED' 
            END as Name
     FROM USERTABLE UT
)

SELECT Name, COUNT_BIG(*) AS cnt
FROM t
GROUP BY Name;
```